# How to create a create table statement in a loop in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create multiple tables with just one statement (query).

```
Loop
    start
    (
        create table a
    )
    a =a +1
end loop
```

So say it has to create 100 tables labeled as `TABLE1`, `TABLE2`, ...

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more...

Comment: 100 tables same column names and datatype ?

Comment: what will be the attributes of those created tables?

Comment: Yes, that is correct of the same variables

Comment: create table 1 ( name varchar (70), age int(10) )

Comment: It is _bad_ schema design to have lots of identical tables.  Rethink your task.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `createTableProcTest`;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `createTableProcTest`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT Default 0;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET @a := count + 1;
         SET @statement = CONCAT('Create table Table',@a,' ( name VARCHAR(70), age int );');
         PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
                 EXECUTE stmt;
                 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                 SET count = count + 1;
         IF count=100 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
END LOOP simple_loop;
END//
```

In order to execute just do the following:

`Call createTableProcTest();`

By executing the above procedure 100 tables will be created having name table1,...,table100.
And the table structure would look like following:

[image]

**N:B:** Procedure execution might take several seconds. Don't be impatient.

Answer (score -1):

You need give us more details but, I think is easier to call a stored procedure, inside the loop, to create the procedure.

You need to create a procedure to create the tables you need and call this procedure inside the loop.

Ex:

> CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Create_Table(IN tableName VARCHAR(50)) BEGIN   SET
>   @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tableName, '(column1 INT(11))');
>   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;   EXECUTE stmt;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; END

Now, call the create table procedure inside the loop

> DELIMITER // CREATE FUNCTION CalcIncome ( starting_value INT ) RETURNS
>   INT BEGIN
>
> DECLARE income INT;    SET income = 0;    label1: WHILE income <=
>   50 DO
>        call SP_Create_Table(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),starting_value));    END WHILE label1;    RETURN income; END; // DELIMITER;